# How to get the most searched words in Solr?

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am trying to get the keywords that were searched for the past one week in my Solr. Is there any direct way or API to get this? Or can it be obtained from logs by any means ? If yes, please explain it briefly.

Comment: there is an answer from 2018 as well...

Comment: There is no pre-made solution. Parsing logs is the way to go, unless you want to purchase one of the commercial Solr solutions which may provide built-in analytics

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi. Can you please provide us with examples for commercial Solr solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IDI https://lucidworks.com/products/fusion/ or https://sematext.com/cloud/ for example.